# A statement about closed projective subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$. It is true that $X\cap U_0$, $X\cap U_1$, $X\cap U_2$ irreducible sets implies  X irreducible? I suppose that $X$ is reducible. So, there exists two non-empty open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $X$  such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$. It is a good start or I have to find a counterexample? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think this question and its answer is relevant [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272102/when-does-locally-irreducible-imply-irreducible](click here).

Comment: @FredrikMeyer  It is useful!Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Irreducible is a local condition for connected schemes, but it clearly cannot be local for a disconnected one. When you work in affine charts of projective space, things are "hiding at infinity". So try to construct an example by hiding things at infinity. Things are easier to hide if they are small, e.g. points.

Edit: Consider the closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by the points $[1:0:0]$ and $[0:0:1]$.

Comment: I am confused. Can you give me a counterexample? I saw that this property is avaiable for projective curves.

Comment: @rafa I have edited my answer with a counterexample.