# Every smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ ($n\geq 2$) is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Exercise 10.23(a) from [Gathmann's notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021.pdf):

> Let $n\geq 2$. Prove that every smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is irreducible.

This seems like a very general result, but I fail to find any similar questions asked on Mathematics SE or anywhere else. My idea is to use the fact that smooth means locally irreducible (at every point), and by one of the comments in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272102/when-does-locally-irreducible-imply-irreducible):

> Note that in general (Noetherian though), irreducible is equivalent to locally irreducible and connected;

I only have to show every smooth hypersurface is connected. But I have no idea how to show this and also why the above topological statement is true. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Any ample divisor of positive dimension in a connected variety is connected.

Comment: @Sasha Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Hartshorne, Alegbraic Geometry, III, 7.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y \subset \mathbb P^n$ be a hypersurface, and suppose $Y_1, Y_2 \subset Y$ are two distinct irreducible components of $Y$. Then by Bezout's theorem [H, Thm I.7.7], $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have a non-empty intersection
$$\emptyset \subsetneq Y_1 \cap Y_2 \subsetneq Y$$
and $Y$ will be singular along $Y_1 \cap Y_2$, because it is not locally irreducible.

---

Note that this really needs the surrounding $\mathbb P^n$. For example on the surface $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$, the curves $\mathbb P^1 \times \{0\}$ and $\mathbb P^1 \times \{\infty\}$ do not intersect.

[H] Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*